# Hyphenation for transliterated Greek

Tags: pdftex, hyphenation, greek

Is there a hyphenation package available for Greek text transliterated into the Roman alphabet?

I'm creating a document that contains many (i.e. several hundred) Greek place names, which are typically long and don't hyphenate well as English text.

I would prefer to mark them semantically as what they are (with a macro) rather than using `\hyphenation` or `\-` and making a guess at the correct hyphenation.

Comment: the patterns available in texlive are all at /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/  and I don't see anything suitable

Comment: Yeah, I looked in the "obvious" places. Actually the Greek rules for hyphenating a group of consonants following a vowel are pretty straightforward (but not the same as English) so if all else fails I might try to implement those myself. Hyphenating vowels is harder (for example `Poe\-ë\-es\-sa` is a genuine transliterated word!) but picking the low hanging fruit and not generating incorrect hyphens might be good enough.

Comment: an alternative to making a new set of patterns (which would mean making a new format) would be to take your list of place names, add hyphens to them all using perl or python or whatever  and then pass the whole list as a `\hyphenation` exception list to pdftex.